# codeigniter ajax form validation with submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have this ajax form validation code igniter. my view is something like this

```
    <?php

      echo form_open('Provinces/create',array('id' => 'form-user'));
    ?>

                <label for="PROVINCE" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2">Province Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PROVINCE" name="PROVINCE" value = "<?= set_value("PROVINCE"); ?>">
                  </div>
                <button class="btn btn-info fa fa-save" type="submit">&nbsp Save</button>
                <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Provinces/index'; ?>' class = 'btn btn-danger fa fa-times-circle'>&nbsp Cancel</a>
     <?php

      echo form_close();
    ?>
```

and i have this javascript

```
<script>

    $('#form-user').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var me = $(this);

        // perform ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: me.attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: me.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success == true) {
                    // if success we would show message
                    // and also remove the error class
                    $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
                        ' Data has been saved' +
                        '</div>');
                    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                                    .removeClass('has-success');
                    $('.text-danger').remove();

                    // reset the form
                    me[0].reset();

                    url = "<?php echo site_url('Provinces/ajax_add')?>";
                           // ajax adding data to database
                      $.ajax({
                        url : url,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $('#form').serialize(),
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                           alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            alert('Error adding / update data');
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                        var element = $('#' + key);
                        element.closest('div.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger')
                        .remove();
                        element.after(value)
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

i have found this code on google and just customized it. but the problem is, i am not that familiar with ajax, the part where the form validation fails, work perfectly fine, but when it is succes, even though it shows `alert('success');` it doesnt add the value in the database. i need to finish this projects in a few weeks. please help.

here is where i get the validations,

```
public function create(){


    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PROVINCE','Province Name','trim|required|max_length[30]|callback_if_exist');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"','</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this)){

        $data['success'] = true;
    }else{
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            # code...
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

also here is my ajax_add

```
public function ajax_add()
{
    $data = array(
            'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'),
        );
    $insert = $this->Provinces_Model->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

and here is my model,

```
public function save($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: `success` will fire based on the request itself succeeding and no http error status and some valid json returned when dataType is json. You need to validate that the actual insert succeeds and set `status` based on that and also check the value of status in the ajax success

Comment: `'Provinces/ajax_add'` will this code is for calling for file or file and function ? Are you sure that you are calling ajax_add() ? Try by adding `ajax_add()` in the last line of ajax file.

Comment: @charlietfl how can i do something like that, please have an answer and modify my code, thanks

Comment: @Rishi `'Provinces/ajax_add'` part is insert function on other open source. i just modified it. put it together.. but i think, theres something missing in my codes to make the two fit together

Answer (score 0):

1. You dont't need to use uppercase when accessing your controller

just use

```
 url = "<?php echo site_url('provinces/ajax_add')?>";
```

2. Validation the request data before inserting

try

```
public function ajax_add()
{
   $response = array(
       'success' => false 
    ) ;

   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   // add your validation
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('PROVINCE', 'PROVINCE', 'required');

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {

       $data = array(
        'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE')
        );

        $insert = $this->Provinces_Model->save($data);
        if($insert){
            $response['success'] = TRUE ;
            $response['message'] = 'Record created successfully' ;
         }
         else{
           $response['message'] = 'Unable to create record' ;
         }
   }
   else
   {
       $response['message'] = 'Invalid data' ;
   }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Then check for the 'message' index in your ajax response in the javascript code

This will give an idea of where there is problem, whether its from the

1. view or
2. controller or'
3. Model

Comment: `Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected` '=' on this part `        $insert = $this->Provinces_Model->save($data);
        if($insert){
            response['success'] = TRUE ;
            response['message'] = 'Record created successfully' ;`

Comment: Sorry my bad.  I have updated  where I used 'response' instead of '$response'

Comment: i think were not on the same page. i will update my question so you can see it more @Wakeel

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it. just did put

```
        $data = array(
                'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'),
            );
        $insert = $this->Provinces_Model->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
```

into my controller, which makes my controller

```
public function create(){


    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PROVINCE','Province Name','trim|required|max_length[30]|callback_if_exist');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"','</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this)){


        $data['success'] = true;
        $data = array(
                'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'),
            );
        $insert = $this->Provinces_Model->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

    }else{
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            # code...
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and my javascript

```
$('#form-user').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this);

    // perform ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: me.attr('action'),
        type: 'post',
        data: me.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if (response.success == true) {
                // if success we would show message
                // and also remove the error class
                $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
                    ' Data has been saved' +
                    '</div>');
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                                .removeClass('has-success');
                $('.text-danger').remove();

                // reset the form
                me[0].reset();
                $('.alert-success').delay(500).show(10, function() {
                    $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                })

            }else{
                $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                    var element = $('#' + key);
                    element.closest('div.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error')
                    .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                    .find('.text-danger')
                    .remove();
                    element.after(value)
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```